# Facebook IOS SDK trying to make singleton class?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hy, i am trying to make from Facebook IOS SDK (Octomber 2011) a class of my own in where i can make all the methods and functions that i need and just import this class in any of my application view controllers and call it. 
So this way i don't need to do all the initialization and delegation to the controllers in where i use the facebook.
So i want to do like this, [myfacebookclass initwithappID:myappid]
[myfacebookclass postmessage:@"some message"];

The thing is when i am seting authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES flags in facebook.m ( the original class) and i do a postmessage it redirects me on Facebook Application or Safari and check's for permision, i hit ok and then redirects me in my application and doesn't post message.

WHen i am trying to post message i do like this :

This is in my own facebook class

```
myfacebookclass *facebook2;
+(void)initWithAppID:(NSString*) facebookAppId {
    if (facebook2 == nil) {
        facebook2 = [myfacebookclass new];
        [facebook2 setWithAppId:facebookAppId];        
    }
}

- (void) postMessage1:(NSString *)messageToPost {  
    if ([self.facebook isSessionValid]) {        
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       self.applicationID, @"api_key",
                                       messageToPost,  @"message",
                                       nil];
        [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    } else {
        NSArray * neededPermissions = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_about_me", @"publish_stream", nil] autorelease];
        [self.facebook authorize:neededPermissions];    
    }
}

+ (void)postMessage:(NSString*) message {
        [facebook2 postMessage1:message];
}
```

I also implemented:

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
>     sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
>     {
>     return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
>     }

i've didn't modified facebook.m or other classes in Facebook IOS SDK.

Comment: This is not all my class, is just some methods, i've implemened here all the steps from [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

Answer (score 3):

a good practice when making a singleton class is to use shared instance. Correct singleton also has to include some memory management overridden methods. In your case it can be done like this:

```
@implementation FacebookManager

static FacebookManager *mySharedFacebookManager;

+ (FacebookManager*)sharedFacebookManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(mySharedFacebookManager == nil) {
            mySharedFacebookManager = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return mySharedFacebookManager;
}


+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {    
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(mySharedFacebookManager == nil) {
            mySharedFacebookManager = [super allocWithZone:zone];   
            return mySharedFacebookManager;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;    
}


- (id)retain {  
    return self;    
}


- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;
}


- (oneway void)release {

}


- (id)autorelease {
    return self;    
}
```

In your case you may have Facebook type object as ivar, and some methods to wrap over FB API, for example like this:

```
- (id)init {
 self = [super init];
 if(self) {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APP_ID andDelegate:self];
// restore previous session
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    ...
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)login {
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"user_about_me", @"publish_stream", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
}

- (void)postToFeed:(NSString*)messageToPost {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   messageToPost, @"message",
                                   nil];


    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
}
```

From other classes which have to deal with Facebook the construction is simple:

```
[[FacebookManager sharedFacebookManager] login];

...

[[FacebookManager sharedFacebookManager] postToFeed:@"Hello World!"];
```

I hope this snippets will help you.

To manage your facebook session you have to remember accessToken manually in FBSessionDelegate methods like that:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}


- (void)fbDidLogout {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Yes is a good idea with memory management, i will do this, but my main problem is that if i use check if the user is logged in already, using safari or Facebook application, the session remains invalid (facebook isSessionValid) and i can't post message ore anything else.

Comment: @MykeAndreas Now I understand. I completed the code above with FBSessionDelegate methods and modification in init method. Hope now it will works for you.

Comment: Yes but didlogin and didlogout aren't called because you don't use the application to login or logout, you just check if you are logged in and if not you use FBApplication to log in or Safari, this is if you set WithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES from facebook.m !

Comment: But I don't understand why you trying to call `- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth` manually. This is private method from facebook.m.  `- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions` is public and make the choice automatically.. From FB doc: _* If the device supports multitasking, we use fast app switching to show the dialog in the Facebook app or, if the Facebook app isn't installed, in Safari._ 
Did you override `- (BOOL)application:handleOpenURL:` in app delegate?

Comment: The thing is that in my application isSessionValid is allways false, because didlogin doesn't get called. My application works if i set the falgs authorizeWithFBAppAuth and authorizeWithFBAppAuth to NO, But if i set them to YES didlogin doesn't get called.

Comment: looks good but when i try to use it it sends me for permissions to the safari, i press ok, back to my app and nothing happens. do u know what i might be missing?